# How to publish All Images on Publishing site,

Tags: publishing

I must have got a Publish Site because of menu. I have got a Question - How Turn of the publish element on Images. I have got a lot of images with work status, and after I choose Public I have got accepted. How could I turn of the publicity function for images ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the content approval for a given library, but not for a specific file type. So, I would suggest putting all images in a separate library and turn off approval.

Comment: But where Can I turn of this? I go to the Library and don't see any workflow

Comment: Go to Library Settings -> Versioning Settings -> Require content approval for submitted items? Select No

Comment: let the PowerShell disable versioning and/or content approval on all image libraries: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Disable-a-versioning-on-91c47409